# TeXShop ignoring the % !TEX root directive

Tags: texshop

I use LaTeX across platforms and most editors understand "% !TEX root = main.tex" type directives, which are very convenient when dealing with large documents.

I am assuming it must be a dumb question, but I don't seem to be able to pull it off with TexShop 5.25... I cannot typeset from a child tex file. Any help is appreciated!

Here is a prototype for the situation: main.tex compiles fine, but not child.tex

child.tex

```
% !TeX root = main.tex
Testing
```

main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input child.tex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the main file in the same folder as the child document?

Comment: I don't know if texshop is case sensitive, but for the off-chance: can you try with `% !TeX root =`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz It doesn't make a difference to use TEX or TeX, I tried both ways.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz The files are all in the same directory.

Comment: By the way, I typeset this with no problem in Linux or windows,  using TeXWorks.

Comment: Ah, in this case I'm out of ideas. I hope a texshop user will soon see your question and be able to help!

Comment: Works for me if you use: `% !TEX root = ./main.tex` or `% !TEX root = main.tex`